# Migrate Custom Filter Attribute Unit Test from .NET Framework to .NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, asp.net-core

I have a .NET Framework 4.7.2 MVC App that I am migrating to a .NET Core 2.1 App.  Everything is working so far however I cannot get one of the Unit Tests that was testing a custom Attribute I wrote working in the .NET Core Version.

This is the code for the Attribute Test in the Framework Version

```
    private HttpActionContext _successContext;
    private HttpActionContext _failContext;
    private HttpControllerContext _controllerContext;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        _controllerContext = new HttpControllerContext
        {
            Request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, string.Empty)
            {
                Content = new ObjectContent(typeof(string), string.Empty, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter())
            }
        };

        _successContext = new HttpActionContext {ControllerContext = _controllerContext};
        _successContext.ModelState.Add("TestField", new ModelState());

        _failContext = new HttpActionContext { ControllerContext = _controllerContext };
        _failContext.ModelState.Add("TestField", new ModelState());
        _failContext.ModelState.AddModelError("TestField", "Test error message");

    }
```

What is the correct way to new up a HttpControllerContext and ActionContext in .NET Core version?

Or is this the incorrect approach to test an Attribute in .NET Core?

This is the Frameowrk version of the Attribute that is under test

```
public class JsonValidationFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid) return;
        var errorMessages = actionContext.ModelState.Values
            .SelectMany(modelState => modelState.Errors.Select(x => x.ErrorMessage));
        actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, Json.Encode(errorMessages));
    }
}
```

This is how I have developed that attribute in .NET Core version (it is working as expected but I just need to re-implement Unit Test for it.

```
public class JsonValidationFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid) return;
        IEnumerable<string> errorMessages = actionContext.ModelState.Values.SelectMany(modelState => modelState.Errors.Select(x => x.ErrorMessage));
        actionContext.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(errorMessages);
    }
}
```

Comment: What you actually need is a `ActionExecutingContext` for your attribute test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the .Net Core version of the attribute, what you actually need is a `ActionExecutingContext` for your attribute test

For example

```
// Arrange
var context = new ActionExecutingContext(
    new ActionContext
    {
        HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext(),
        RouteData = new RouteData(),
        ActionDescriptor = new ActionDescriptor()
    },
    new List<IFilterMetadata>(),
    new Dictionary<string, object>(),
    new object());

context.ModelState.AddModelError("TestField", "Test error message");

var filter = new JsonValidationFilterAttribute();

// Act
filter.OnActionExecuting(context);

// Assert
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(context.Result, typeof(BadRequestObjectResult));
//context.Result.Should().BeOfType<BadRequestObjectResult>(); Fluent Assertions
```

Comment: I will give this a go

Comment: Nkosi - could you update you answer to incllude what the Assert should be when using MSTest?  Is the Assert above NUnit?  I am using MS Test for my Testing Framework

Comment: I used -  Assert.IsInstanceOfType(context.Result, typeof(BadRequestObjectResult));

Comment: Nkosi - how would I test that it returns a successful response if no errors on the validation filter?

Comment: By not adding a mode error to the model state of the context

Comment: I tried the same code but plugged in context.ModelState.SetModelValue("test", 1, "1"); instead of the AddModelError and then I called out context.Result into its own variable to test it but its null?

Comment: It will be null because no result will have been set. In live code that would be handled further down in the pipeline

Comment: so what would the Assert be?  That context.ModelState.IsValid = true

Comment: You assert that the context's result is null which would assert that `if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid) return;` was invoked for the attribute code you provided originally