# How To Write Unit Test For CustomActionFilter In DotNet Core

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I have custom action filter and i want to write unit test for that in dotnet core weabpi.

please help.

```
public class ApplicationIdValidationAttribute: IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var param = context.ActionArguments["Id"];

        var modelState = context.ModelState;
        if (param!=null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(param.ToString()))
        {
            modelState.AddModelError("id", "Application id is required");
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(new ModelStateRequestValidationAdaptor(modelState));
            return;
        }

        if (!Guid.TryParse(param?.ToString(), out Guid applicationGuid))
        {
            modelState.AddModelError("id", "Application id is not a valid Guid");
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(new ModelStateRequestValidationAdaptor(modelState));
            return;
        }
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of unit test or assertions are you looking to do? Your question (as-is) is very vague on your expected answer.

Comment: i want to assert badrequest in unit test case.

Comment: There is an entire section dedicated on how to run unit tests for ASP.NET Core over at the Microsoft Docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-dotnet-test?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: @rakeshmahur if you take a look at an answer I gave here recently it should provide some help https://stackoverflow.com/a/54109082/5233410